# Save image from url to App in some folder like tmp,document for offline use

Tags: image, react-native, offline-mode

I want to save image once loaded URL, then save them in at some place like document or tmp folder and in offline mode to use saved images.

I have tried with `react-native-fs`, but did not succeed, it gives error.

Answer (score 0):

you can save images from a url by converting the images to base64. Afterwhich, you can do anything with the image such rebuilding/writing the bytes to real image.

Comment: without converting image to base64 possible?

Answer (score 0):

let try this.

```
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob'
import Share from 'react-native-share'
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs'
import {Alert, Platform} from 'react-native'

const download = (url) => {
  let dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs
  try {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    const configOptions = { fileCache: true }
      RNFetchBlob.config(configOptions)
        .fetch('GET', url, {
          'Authorization': '', //yourTokenIfHave
          'Content-Type': '' // 'application/octet-stream'
        })
        .then(resp => {
          return resp.readFile('base64')
        })
        .then(async base64Data => {
          base64Data = `data:application/pdf;base64,` + base64Data
          await Share.open({ url: base64Data })
          // remove the image or pdf from device's storage
          await RNFS.unlink(filePath)
        })
    } else {
      RNFetchBlob
        .config({
          fileCache: true,
          path: dirs.DocumentDir + `/${itemPDF.fileName}`
        })
        .fetch('GET', url, {
          'Authorization': '',
          'Content-Type': '' // 'application/octet-stream'
        })
        .then(async (res) => {

          // the temp file path
          if (res && res.path()) {
            const filePath = res.path()
            let options = {
              type: 'application/pdf',
              url: filePath
            }
            await Share.open(options)
            await RNFS.unlink(filePath)
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('download: ', error)
  }
}
```